# How to install python module websockets with pip

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, pip

I'm trying to install the python module websockets with pip and I get this setup error message :

```
:~$ pip install websockets
Collecting websockets
  Using cached websockets-4.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qzcf51/websockets/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        with open(readme_file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qzcf51/websockets/
```

I tried to change the language of my prompt like this :

```
export LANG=
```

no issue I checked  `pip update` :

```
:~$ pip install -U setuptools pip
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

My version of python is Python 2.7.12

Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`websockets` is a Python3-only module, you cannot use it with Python 2.7.

Comment: I donwlaoded the module from [pypi.python.org] web site and I opened setup.py I found this `websockets requires Python >= 3.4.`